# Does non-standard analysis lead to different PDEs from those obtained through standard analysis?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, nonstandard-analysis

Take the Navier-Stokes equations as an example. If we take a non-standard analysis approach, will the final form of the PDEs be different from what presented in classical books on fluid dynamics?

Comment: The point of nonstandard analysis is to get to the same theorems as standard analysis, so I'd say the answer is "no", but I'm not sure how to flesh this out into a full answer

Comment: What do you mean by taking a non-standard analysis approach to writing down the Navier-Stokes equations?